# JS form inputs not registering after changing tabs

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using webpack to dynamically create a to do list website. I have tabs for different content. The default load tab has a form that can be filled out that sends data to local storage. Form inputs work fine upon load, however when I switch tabs and go back to the default page, form inputs are not registering.

I am logging every input from the form (text area input, date, priority) into console to see the expected output it will send to local storage. On default page load (my 'all tab') form inputs work fine, but they do not work when I switch back from any other tab that I have.

After switching tabs, the text area input logs as empty and so does the date. However, the priority radio buttons will still register correctly.

```
function makeForm() {
        const form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('id', 'task-form');

        const textInput = document.createElement('textarea');
        textInput.setAttribute('id', 'task-input');
        textInput.required = 'true';
        textInput.placeholder = 'Enter task here';
        form.appendChild(textInput);

        const date = document.createElement('input');
        date.type = 'date';
        date.setAttribute('id', 'task-due-date');
        const dateLabel = document.createElement('label');
        dateLabel.setAttribute('for', 'due-date');
        dateLabel.textContent = 'Complete by:';
        form.appendChild(dateLabel);
        form.appendChild(date);

        const priorityDiv = makePriorityDiv();
        form.appendChild(priorityDiv);

        const buttonDiv = document.createElement('div');
        buttonDiv.classList.add('button-div');

        const addBtn = document.createElement('input');
        addBtn.type = 'submit';
        addBtn.value = 'Add';
        buttonDiv.appendChild(addBtn);

        const cancelBtn = document.createElement('button');
        cancelBtn.textContent = 'Cancel';
        cancelBtn.classList.add('form-btn');
        cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', cancel);
        buttonDiv.appendChild(cancelBtn);
        form.appendChild(buttonDiv);

        form.addEventListener('submit', addToLocalStorage);

        return form;
    }
```

```
    function addToLocalStorage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const parentDiv = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;

        inputValue = document.getElementById('task-input').value;
        dateValue = document.getElementById('task-due-date').value;
        priorityValue = document.querySelector('input[name="priority"]:checked').value;

        console.log(`before adding to local storage: 
        input: ${inputValue}
        date: ${dateValue}
        priorty: ${priorityValue}`);

        document.getElementById('task-form').reset();

        parentDiv.classList.add('hidden');
    }
```

Comment: you could try adding the event listener to the form again each time you switch back to the tab that contains the form. You can do this by calling `form.addEventListener('submit', addToLocalStorage);` again when the tab is shown.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Every time I switch back to the tab the form module is being called again. I have confirmed addToLocalStorage is being called every time. My problem is that whatever form data I input after switching tabs is not registering at all (aside from priority radio buttons).

Comment: How are you adding and retrieving the values to and from the localStorage? Are they present when you check the Storate > Local storage in your browser?

Comment: Every time a tab is loaded localStorage is being accessed to display the items. They are present. My solution to this so far has been to decouple the form from the tab itself, that has done the trick. Would like to understand the mechanism behind why it wasn't working though.